Changing properties for particle effects of the particle pack from Unity Technologies
Problem
The Unity Particle Pack provides particle effects in form of prefabs, where multiple particle systems are used to combine the whole effect. That leads to the problem that if I want to change a property of the visual effect, I can't just change a property of one particle system.
Prefab (BigExplosion)
The whole prefab:

ParticleSystems in the prefab:

Example Code
GameObject particle = (GameObject) PrefabUtility.InstantiatePrefab(ParticlePrefab, transform);
particle.transform.position = position;
particle.transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
ParticleSystem particleSystem = particle.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();

ParticleSystem.MainModule main = particleSystem.main;
main.simulationSpace = ParticleSystemSimulationSpace.World;

ParticleSystem.CollisionModule collision = particleSystem.collision;
collision.enabled = true;
collision.type = ParticleSystemCollisionType.World;
collision.sendCollisionMessages = true;


What is the question?

How to change a property so that it affects the whole visual effect.

It is unclear the desired effect you want.  Please update your post to include the question, example of what you are trying to do, and expected result.  Without details, the best i can suggest is a for loop.

Use GetComponentsInChildren<T>() and modify them all in the same way?
